# Why do my mesh planes get deleted when I bind all objects using control + j?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, 3d-view, export

When I bind all objects the mesh planes get deleted, I’m trying to export it as one piece so any solutions?

Comment: please explain more and a picture can be good

Answer (score 0):

Probably they get moved, not deleted. If so, before joining, select the disappearing objects and press Alt P "Clear and keep transform", then join with Ctrl J.